# tkinter frame waiting conundrum

Tags: tkinter

I'm using 2 frames (A and B) that I switch between to make my program run. 
Previously

```
while Conditions:
    self.frameA.wait_window()
```

Then when I'm finished with frameA:

```
self.frameA.destroy()
self.frameB = FrameB(self)
self.frameB.wait_window()
#After I'm finished with B...
#Function that takes info from frames A and B to make the program run
self.frameB.destroy()
self.frameA = FrameA(self)
```

and alternate back and forth for the duration of the program. But I started thinking that destroying and reinitializing could be done better. Now I created a function for the frames that works like a second init, using grid_forget(). My problem now is that since I'm not destroying the frames, the wait_window never breaks, making an infinite loop. I toyed with the idea of merging the 2 frames, but that won't solve my problem of wait_window. Essentially, is there a way to make my application wait for input from the frames, or is the best solution to just go back to the original method?

```
while firstConditions():
    while secondConditions():
        self.play()
    #Other code after secondConditions is false

def play(self):
    w = messagebox.askyesno(message='Make changes?', parent=self)
    if w:
        #Deals with making changes
    self.frameA.wait_window()
```

Then a button in frameA will lead to frameB being created

```
def makeFrameB(self):
    self.frameA.grid_forget()
    self.frameB.newInit()
    self.frameB.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
    self.frameB.wait_window()
```

My reasoning for using wait_window is that if I don't, I'd get an infinite loop with the messagebox appearing over and over.

Comment: `wait_window` is not designed to be used like you are using it -- it is almost exclusively used to wait for a modal dialog. Why do you think you need the call to `wait_window`? Can you show us a complete working example that illustrates what you're trying to do in just a few lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing the code that posed the issues, I don't need to use wait_window to solve my issues.

Comment: Please explain what you changed.  This question is unlikely to help anyone in the future unless the accepted answer shows how to solve the problem.

Comment: I took Bryan's advice, went through the entire program and removed every instance of ``wait_window`` to resolve my issue.